# GNU GRUB is not showing

Tags: grub2, grubrescue, grub-efi, grub-legacy

I have windows 10 in one hdd(MBR) and on another hdd I fresh installed Ubuntu 20.04 But I'm not getting the option to select which os to boot like earlier. I tried updating grub and also manually setting menu entry but nothing works. [The image  has the boot order list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZw8m.jpg)

Here boot option 1,2,4 is the same hdd on which Ubuntu is installed and boot option 3 is windows.
Please help guys

Comment: Windows with MBR was necessarily installed in Legacy mode (for absolutely no reason in a modern UEFI computer). Then the second OS (Ubuntu) has to be installed in the same mode but Ubuntu was properly installed in UEFI mode. Unless in the same mode Grub can't "see" the first OS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto But earlier it used to work I updated from 20.04 to 22.04 but in 22.04 i was not able to control my GPU fan speed so I came back to 20.04 and then grub was not working

Comment: No, it didn't because it couldn't. It's this simple. It may have worked in the past ONLY if you had both OS installed in the same mode.

Comment: I will try making MBR for ubuntu

Comment: @ChanganAuto i tried on my other system where windows is installed in UEFI and also tried fresh install Ubuntu but the grub menu for selecting os is now showing. Is there any other way?